# Proper #import scheme Objective-C project

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm doing some reorganizing of a semi-large project and I'm not sure the best way to go about it. I cannot decide where to use my #imports <...> across multiple files. I have a "Settings.h" style header that contains a lot of #define's needed by many of my classes. Should I be #importing everything needed by a class into its header? Or should I not import anything into the header and use @class definitions, then save the #import for the actual class.m files?

If this is unclear, let me know and I'll try to reiterate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where possible, prefer `@class` over `#import` in header files.

Result: faster builds and less likely to creaty circular dependencies (A imports B, B imports A).

You can also create a header file that #imports commonly used headers or those headers that are commonly used together, so that you don't need to #import each header individually.

Comment: To clarify about the 'header file that contains commonly used headers', that should probably be a PCH, which will pre-copmile all of those classes for even *faster* build times.

Comment: If you're worried about circular imports from frameworks, or other umbrella headers, use a header include guard macro.  Theoretically, there shouldn't be much of an increase in compile time because each relevant header should only be included once.

Comment: no, I meant a single header that includes multiple commonly used headers, not necessarily pch because it's bad practice to include headers from one's own project in the pch